# Standard Delete button override in salesforce Not redirecting as expected

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi I am trying to override  standard delete button for a object "Claim" for a particular user role to prevent from delete & for other user roles the record should get delete. when i try with below code it prevents from deleting but not redirecting to the desired page mentioned in "Windows.Open()" just showing a blank page.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Claim__c">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var con = {!$User.UserRoleId};
 if(con=='00E90000000ibNs')
 {
   window.onload (alert('Claim Caanot Be deleted'));
   window.open('/a08/o','_self');
  }
</script>   
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of requirement would be best fit to use a trigger on the object with the "before delete" operation.  One primary reason is that you can override action override pages very easily with ?nooverride=1 appended to the URL.

Here is an example of a before delete trigger that will not allow them to bypass easily:

```
trigger prevent on Claim__c (before delete) {
  // do logic here to check if user is allowed to delete
  // e.g. check user's role or look at a custom setting you have setup, etc    
  // here is an example of checking roles, although I much prefer custom settings
  // to hardcoding it as I have done here as they do not require code changes
  // to update in the future
  boolean userAllowed = [select count() from User where UserRole.DeveloperName in ('AllowedRole1','AllowedRole2','AllowedRole3') and Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()] > 0;
  for (Claim__c claim : Trigger.old)
    {
      if(!userAllowed) {
        // user is not allowed to delete, use addError method on the SObject to stop them
        claim.addError('You cannot delete this record!');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
window.location.href = '/a08/o';

to see if a popup blocker is stopping access.

Answer (score 0):

A client-side redirection isn't a reliable solution.
It is better to add an custom controller as extension to your VF page and put the logic
into the Apex Controller.

--------------------Apex Controller Claim_Controller.cls------------------------------
...

public PageReference reDirect() {

PageReference pageRef;

if($User.UserRoleId == 00E90000000ibNs) {

```
  pageRef = new PageReference('/a08/o');
  pageRef.setRedirect(true);
```

}

return pageRef;

}

...